# Dash app very slow - need to optimise my code but don't know where to start

Tags: python, optimization, plotly, plotly-dash

My app only has two figures on it but is already running really slowly. It technically works (i.e. clicking on a value in the dropdown changes the figures but there's a ~20 second lag between clicking something and the expected behaviour happening on screen. My MacBook also sounds like a jet engine while running the app if that gives anyone any clues). Is there anything I can do to make it run faster?  The dataset I'm using is pretty chunky - 2.6 million rows. Is that too big for a dash app to handle without being so slow?

I'll include my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/darkly/bootstrap.min.css'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import and clean dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data_with_long_lat.csv')
df.columns = [col.lower() for col in df.columns]



df.rename(columns = {'downo' : 'day num'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'daytype' : 'day'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'downo' : 'day of week'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'jnytyp' : 'jny type'}, inplace=True)


dropdown_style = {
            'width': '50%',  
            'font-size': '16px', 
            'color': '#141718', 
            'border-radius': '4px',
            'border': '2px solid #343a40', 
            'background-color': '#b8c2cd', 
            'padding': '10px',
            'box-shadow': '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get unique station names
xstations = df['startstn'].unique()

# Create a dictionary to map station names to their string representations
station_dict = {str(station): station for station in xstations}

# Create a list of dictionaries for dropdown options
station_dropdown = [{'label': key.strip().title(), 'value': value} for key, value in station_dict.items()]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Transport for London - One Week in 2009", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='select_mode',
                 options=[
                     {"label": 'Bus', "value": "LTB"},
                     {"label": 'Underground', "value": "LUL"},
                     {"label": 'National Rail', "value": "NR"},
                     {"label": 'Docklands Light Railway', "value": "DLR"},
                     {"label": 'Overground', "value": "LRC"},
                     {"label": 'Tram', "value": "TRAM"}],
                 multi=False,
                 value='LUL',  # London Underground will be the initial/defualt value
                 style=dropdown_style
                 ),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='select_station',
                 options=station_dropdown,
                 searchable=False,
                 multi=False,
                 placeholder='Search for a station',
                 style=dropdown_style,
                 value = None
                 ),
    html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
    html.Br(),  # break line

    dcc.Graph(id='jny_by_day', figure={}),
    dcc.Graph(id='jny_by_startstn', figure={})
])


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect graphs with Dash components
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id = 'output_container', component_property = 'children'), # Output will be children in html.Div.
     Output(component_id = 'jny_by_day', component_property = 'figure'),
     Output(component_id = 'jny_by_startstn', component_property = 'figure')], # Don't use square brackets if only one Output
    [Input(component_id = 'select_mode', component_property = 'value'),
     Input(component_id = 'select_station', component_property = 'value')]
)

def update_graph(mode_slctd, station_slctd): # each argument connects to an input (above). One input = one argument, two inputs = two arguments etc. The argument always refers to the component property
    print(mode_slctd)
    print(type(mode_slctd))
    print(station_slctd)
    print(type(station_slctd))

    container = f"The mode of transport chosen by the user was: {mode_slctd}"

    bar_chart_df = df.copy()
    bar_chart_df = bar_chart_df[(bar_chart_df['subsystem'] == mode_slctd) & (bar_chart_df['startstn'] == station_slctd)]


    # Build bar chart
    order_of_days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    jny_by_day = bar_chart_df['day'].value_counts()
    jny_by_day_df = jny_by_day.reset_index()
    jny_by_day_df.columns = ['Day', 'Journeys']
    bar_chart = px.bar(jny_by_day_df, x = 'Day', y = 'Journeys',
                       title = 'Number of Journeys Each Day',
                       labels = {'Day' : 'Day', 'Journeys' : 'Journeys'},
                       template = 'plotly_dark',
                       category_orders= {'Day' : order_of_days})


   # Calculate the number of journeys from each start station
    scatterplot_df = df.copy()
    scatterplot_df = scatterplot_df[(scatterplot_df['subsystem'] == mode_slctd) ]
    scatterplot_df['startstn'] = scatterplot_df['startstn'].str.title().str.strip()
    start_station_counts = scatterplot_df['startstn'].value_counts().reset_index()
    start_station_counts.columns = ['startstn', 'num_journeys']

    # Merge with the original dataframe to get longitude and latitude
    merged_df = pd.merge(start_station_counts, scatterplot_df[['startstn', 'longitude', 'latitude']], on='startstn', how='left')

    # Create the scatter plot with longitude, latitude, and number of journeys
    scatter_plot = px.scatter_mapbox(merged_df, lat='latitude', lon='longitude', hover_name='startstn',
                                    hover_data={'startstn' : True, 'num_journeys': ':,.0f', 'longitude' : False, 'latitude' : False}, 
                                    title = 'Number of Journeys Started at Each Station',
                                    size='num_journeys',
                                    labels={'num_journeys': 'Number of Journeys'},
                                    size_max = 15,
                                    color='num_journeys',  # Color of points based on number of journeys
                                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis,
                                    zoom=10,  # Set the initial zoom level
                                    mapbox_style="open-street-map")

    

    return container, bar_chart, scatter_plot # what is returned here goes into the output. If you have two outputs you have to return two things here. The order of the return matters

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

tried to move df processing outside of callback function but still slow

Comment: you are seriously rasterizing 2.6 million interactive scatter points ?! think about other ways you can present your data, maybe a histogram instead.

Comment: @AhmedAEK is that what is making my app really slow? Maybe I can take a 10% sample of my df for the map

Comment: or even better, enforce some filters on the user that reduce the number of scatter points you have to draw, most computers can handle 10k points, maybe push it to 100k and you start lagging, 2.6 million is just a no go, might as well use a 2D histogram instead.

Comment: btw its a scatter_mapbox not a scatterplot, should have made that clear. So what I am doing is visualising the number of journeys started at various London TfL stations on a map of London - I thought the more data the better

Comment: What filters do do you have in mind @AhmedAEK ?

Comment: first i'd start by benchmarking the code and see how much time is spent in each function, using `cProfile` without dash, if dash turns out to be the problem then you should either down-sample those 2.6 million points before drawing, or using another representation like a heat map, you could also add filters like time or location to narrow down the data and not have to draw the entire 2.6 million points, in reality no one has the time to go through 2.6 million points, so there is no point drawing them.